# No entry point. Program does not contain a suitable 'Main' method

Tags: c#, class, program-entry-point

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CLASSES_2
{
    class Building
    {
        public int Area; // total square footage of building
        public int Floors; // number of floors
        public int Occupants; // number of occupants
    }
    class Building_Demo
    {
       static void main(string[] args)
        {
            Building house = new Building();
            int Area_Per_Person;

            house.Area = 4000;
            house.Floors = 7;
            house.Occupants = 10;

            Area_Per_Person = house.Area / house.Occupants;

            Console.WriteLine("The house has: \n" + house.Floors + " Floors \n" + house.Occupants + " Occupants"
                + house.Area + "Area \n" + Area_Per_Person + " Area_Per_Person: ");
        }
  }
}
```

Can Someone tell me what's wrong with my code? It's telling me that there is no Method suitable for an entry point.

> CS5001 Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Method names are case sensitive. The method should be called `Main`, with a capital M, not `main` like you currently have:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
```

Comment: It works thank you.

Comment: @Fakhr, please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267491/1997232).